# Resolving CocoaPods child dependency conflict

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

CocoaPods keeps complaining about two dependencies requiring conflicting versions of `Protobuf`:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Protobuf":
  In Podfile:
    flutter_blue (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_blue/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      flutter_blue/Protos (= 0.0.1) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
        Protobuf (~> 3.11.4)

    mobile_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/mobile_scanner/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (~> 2.6.0) was resolved to 2.6.0, which depends on
        MLKitBarcodeScanning (~> 1.7.0) was resolved to 1.7.0, which depends on
          MLKitVision (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
            Protobuf (~> 3.12)

There are only pre-release versions available satisfying the following requirements:

        'Protobuf', '~> 3.11.4'

        'Protobuf', '~> 3.12'

You should explicitly specify the version in order to install a pre-release version
```

It has a suggestion:

```
You should explicitly specify the version in order to install a pre-release version
```

How do I do that?

I tried adding

```
pod "Protobuf", "3.12"
```

But it simply complains again:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Protobuf":
  In Podfile:
    Protobuf (= 3.12)

    flutter_blue (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_blue/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      flutter_blue/Protos (= 0.0.1) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
        Protobuf (~> 3.11.4)

Specs satisfying the `Protobuf (= 3.12), Protobuf (~> 3.11.4)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Answer (score 0):

The package **flutter_blue** is not getting any more updates, so the way I fixed this exact issue was by using this package instead: **flutter_blue_plus** (which is a continuation of flutter_blue)

Link to package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus